# cassandra 2.0.4 Unable to initialize MemoryMeter

Tags: cassandra

I've upgraded cassandra from 1.2.13 to 2.0.4 on a cluster of 5 nodes.
when i run nodetool -h localhost ring I see this errormessage in the end:

ERROR 10:33:28,324 Unable to initialize MemoryMeter (jamm not specified as javaagent).  This means Cassandra will be unable to measure object sizes accurately and may consequently OOM.

according to this:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6404

it should be fixed. 
i'm running java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.45-1jpp.2.el6_4.x86_64.

this is the beginning of the process options:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.45.x86_64/jre/bin/java -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra//lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar

is there anyone who could point me in a direction where too look for a solution?

these error's, are they serious or mere cosmetic?

//john

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this error only emits from tools, then ignore. If you also see it in your output.log or system.log, then it can be problematic. It seems your version of JVM is good. If the command prompt you pasted here is from Cassandra process, then you are good. Tools have a different script to initialize their environment. Check cassandra/bin folder and inspect tools' scripts to see if they include this change:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12615604/0001-Set-javaagent-when-running-tools-in-bin.patch

Chances are somehow your upgrade process didn't change them.

Comment: For me this command solved the problem: `export JAVA_OPTIONS=-javaagent:$TITAN_HOME/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar`