# Sstableloader Exception in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I created a sstable using csv file.I wanted to those sstables into cassandra data folder using sstableloader option in windows. The sstables is created in the fallowing folder.

D:\Itopcode\cassandrasstablel\sampledemo\users.

This sstables is created using SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter class.

Those keyspace and sstable or columnfamily schema also defined in cassandra using cqlsh3.0.

My cassandra version is 2.0.

My Keyspace is

```
  CREATE KEYSPACE sampledemo
     WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy' };
```

My sstable is

```
  CREATE TABLE sampledemo.users (
        key uuid,
        firstname ascii,
        lastname ascii,
        password ascii,
        age ascii,
        email ascii,
        PRIMARY KEY (key));
```

I run the following

D:\cassandra\bin>sstableloader -d 127.0.0.1 D:/Itopcode/cassandrasstablel/sampledemo/users

And Exception is

**Established connection to initial hosts
Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream
Streaming relevant part of D:\Itopcode\cassandrasstablel\sampledemo\users\sampledemo-users-jb-1-Data.db to []**

Comment: You should do some searching around before posting questions.  This looks to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329314/cassandra-2-0-4-unable-to-initialize-memorymeter?rq=1

Comment: My problem is not about memory meter.When I trying to load the sstables into cassandra live cluster using sstableloader its not streaming the data..

Comment: can you paste the entire exception?

Comment: Entire Exception is                                                                  Established connection to initial hosts Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream Streaming relevant part of D:\Itopcode\cassandrasstablel\sampledemo\users\sampledemo-users-jb-1-Data.db to []                                                                     What I am posted in Bold that is the cause of to stop loading the sstables into cassandra live cluster...

Comment: that is just log information.  there is no exception there.  what else is printed?  please add changes to the original post.

Comment: D:\cassandra\bin>sstableloader -d localhost D:/Itopcode/cassandrasstablel/sampledemo/users
Established connection to initial hosts
Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream
Streaming relevant part of D:\Itopcode\cassandrasstablel\sampledemo\users\sampledemo-users-jb-1-Data.db to [].                                                                                                                                             **The entire message is getting only this one when I am run Sstableloader in cassandra.May be its not establishing connection to cluster.**